# Is it mandatory to specify --style argument and --tag-transform-script in osm2pgsql query for importing .pbf file?

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, mapnik, osm2pgsql

I am trying to build a tile server that serves tiles of multiple styles(osm and osm-bright). I have followed this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79077/serving-multiple-styles-from-tile-server) for implementing this. But [here](https://ircama.github.io/osm-carto-tutorials/tile-server-ubuntu/#load-data-to-postgis) I found that osm2pgsql query for importing .pdf file is specifing the --style argument and --tag-transform-script for importing data to postgres database.

```
osm2pgsql -s -C 300 -c -G --hstore --style openstreetmap-carto.style --tag- 
transform-script openstreetmap-carto.lua -d gis -H $HOSTNAME -U postgres 
[.osm or .pbf file]
```

So my question is that - Is it mandatory to use --style argument and --tag-transform-script osm2pgsql? If yes , what should be the alternate way for serving multiple styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the style you want to render.

Without `--style`, the default.style for importing will be used, and the `--tag-transform-script` **can** be used, but not mandatory. I have never used it with my own Mapnik style.

See https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/docs/usage.md for the complete options description.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to use same database for multiple carto style ( in my case, I want to use osm and osm bright)?

Comment: Surely. Make sure that your style file contains all fields that are inside openstreetmap-carto.style and the standard default.style that is used for osm-bright.